# Persisting JSON response using Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin

There are plenty of tutorials on how to persist GORM objects to MongoDB e.g. http://blog.mongodb.org/post/18510469058/grails-in-the-land-of-mongodb. In my case, I am getting HTTP responses from one a request from one server to another.   I do not know the exact shape of the JSON responses but have a very good idea of most of the structure.

So say I am getting a list of Doctors, I know the structure of a Doctor.  Each Doctor has a list of patients but I do not know the exact structure of each patient.

One patient might be:

```
patient : {
    name: "tony",
    lastIllness: "flu"
}
```

wheras another might be:

```
patient : {
   name: "peter",
   phoneNumber: "08678762"
}
```

My goal is to persist the JSON response exactly as it is when I get it from the HTTP requests into MongoDB and make it user friendly, that means to be able to run different queries for various patients / doctors.

I could do:

```
class Doctor {
    List<Patient> patients
    static embedded = ['patients']
}

class Patient {
    // holds dynamic attributes
}
```

I could manually parse the JSON and create the various Patient attributes dynamically by doing something like:

```
patient[$attributeName]=attributeValue
```

This will work but I can see the parsing being getting more complicated and buggy. Remember, I want the JSON I get back from the HTTP request to be persisted verbatim and I want this JSON to be usable for queries.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I had a slightly similar case. I've created a Restful API with Grails and the customer wants to store every request to the API with all the params in MongoDB to be able to extract usage information.

I created the following domain class:

```
class ApiStatistic {

    static mapWith = "mongo"

    ObjectId id
    ...
    Map parameters
    Date dateCreated
```

}

Then, in a filter that intercepts all the request I call asynchronously a service that receives the request params. The interesting attribute here is **parameters** that it's a `Map`.

Then all I've to do is create a new `ApiStatistic` object and assign the params of the request to the `parameters` attribute. The `Map` gets stored in MongoDB as a json with all the information.

I think with this approach you can persist the JSON response in MongoDB without any problem just using a `Map` attribute in your domain class.